# How come "John is friends with Jane"?

Tags: phrases, idioms, nouns, grammatical-number, predicative-complements

The usage in the question title seems [common enough to me](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=is%20friends%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), though it may be more common in Britain.

But I can't exactly see what "part of speech" the word *friends* is here, and I can't come up with any related forms. You'd never hear, for example, *John is enemies with Jack*. What is going on?

Comment: I am really bothered by the usage J "is friends" with...A and B may be friends, A and B may be friendly. But friends with is very awkward, in my opinion. But is it incorrect grammatically?

Comment: Whether it's technically "correct" or not is irrelevant.  It is incredibly idiomatic, and even the most retentive P-ists would laugh at any attempt to excise it from the lexicon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don’t have ‘make enemies with’, but we do have ‘make enemies of’, just as we have ‘make friends of’, so in ‘friends with’, ‘friends’ would appear to be a noun. (The OED has ‘friends with’ under its definitions of ‘friend’ as a noun.) ‘Friends’, because friendship requires two participants as a minumum. It’s not just friends, of course. We can be ‘pals with’, ‘buddies with’, ‘mates with’, ‘chums with’, ‘partners with’ . . .

Comment: *"am mates with"* flatlines in NGrams, and Google behaves very oddly if I search the net for that in quotes. It starts off by saying there are about 394,000 hits, but if I scroll through them it ends up admitting there are only actually 263 in total. I must say *"am partners with"* sounds really weird to me; I suspect the others only seem reasonable because they put me in mind of the familiar *friends* version anyway.

Comment: ...by which I mean: *pals, mates, buddies, chums* are all quite "slangy" terms very closely associated with *friends*, so possibly they're only able to be used in this construction because *friends* has already "blazed the trail", so to speak.

Comment: Yes, that’s probably right. 

I was thinking of ‘partners with’ in the business sense: 'We’ve formed this consortium, so we’ll be partners with our former competitors on this new project.’ Other possibles are ‘collaborators with’, ‘allies with’, ‘bedfellows with’.

‘Mates with’ may not have shown inGrams because it is predominantly colloquial.

Comment: *mates with* takes on the meaning *copulates with* so its unlikely to be used in the plural with the first person, except of course, in slang/informal usage

Comment: 'Aren't you mates with Ed any more?' is a possible, if not highly likely, sentence in BrEng.

Comment: For reasons I can't put my finger on, the *pals, mates, buddies, chums* versions all sound a bit "childish" to me, where *friends* just sounds like a normal construction. I'm starting to get the feeling *be friends with* is really an idiomatic usage that's slightly "bled" into those variants.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I’m not positive, but ‘am collaborators with’ and ‘am allies with’ both strike me as off.  I don’t think I would ever generate them, preferring ‘am a collaborator of’ or ‘am an ally of’.  But I have no problem with ‘am friends with’.  Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. What kind of word class is "friends" in to be/to make/to become friends/good friends with someone"?

The German translation of John is friends with Jane would be John ist mit Jane befreudet. That would be "befriended with" (That word exists in English). English doesn't use "befriended" but it can express the same idea with friends.

One could try to label this "friends" in the mentioned idioms as special adjective limited in use to those idioms. But that jams when "to be good friends with sb" is used. So we have to see "friends" as noun in plural form with special limited use.

I would guess the basis of the idioms is  "John and Jane are friends/good friends" and this expression was artfully twisted and transformed into "John is friends with Jane", maybe to replace a "befriended with", which came out of use.

Idioms don 't care whether they are grammatical or not, they have their own rules.

Etymonline doesn't mention the problem in its entry friend. Perhaps someone can have a look at OED, I have no access.

Comment: The word *befriended* is used in Englishm;  it's not archaic.

Comment: @user1284969632635: we can say "John befriended Jane" to express something that happened, but I don't think we can say "John is befriended with Jane" to express a current state.